# How to access data in R from read.table

Tags: r

I got this text file:

```
a b c d
0 2 8 9
2 0 3 4
8 3 0 2
9 4 2 0
```

I put this command in R:

```
k<-read.table("d:/r/file.txt", header=TRUE)
```

now I want to access the value in row 3 , column 4 (which is 2) ... how can I access it?
Basically my question is how to access table data one by one? I want to use all data separately in nested for loops.
Like:

```
for(row=0;row<4;row++)
for(col=0;col<4;col++)
print data[row][col];
```

Comment: I think you could benefit from having a look into an introduction like [quick R](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html) or, more comprehensive, [An introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Is this what you want? :

```
test <- read.table("test.txt", header = T, fill = T)

for(i in 1:nrow(test)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(test)) {
    print(test[i,j])
  }
}
```

Comment: Working with such for loops is almost never needed in R.

Comment: But wasn't that the original question? Regardless of how usefull is the approach...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to apply a certain operation on each element of matrix.
This is how you could do it, an example

```
A <- matrix(1:16,4,4)
apply(A,c(1,2),function(x) {x %% 5})
```

And operation on the whole row

```
apply(A,1,function(x) sum(x^2))
```